# Cron - bad minute errors in crontab file, can't install

Tags: php, linux, symfony, cron

So I have a `cron` file `sms.cron` that I want to execute every 15 minutes that looks like that:

```
15 * * * * docker-compose exec php bin/console app:send-sms
```

I do not precise the path to the command cause the command is at root and the `sms.cron` as well

I try to run it manualy with command :

```
crontab sms.cron
```

And get the following error:

```
"sms.cron":1: bad minute
errors in crontab file, can't install
```

I get that I have a syntax error but looked at several similar issue on internet and do not see where this error might come from.

Does anyone have any idea on where this syntax error might come from ?
Thanks!

#### UPDATE

Also tried this syntax:

```
*/15 * * * * docker-compose exec php bin/console app:send-sms
```

which returned the following error message :

```
"sms.cron":0: bad minute
errors in crontab file, can't install.
```

Output of `od -c sms.cron`:

```
0000000   `   `   `  \n   *   /   1   5       *       *       *       *
0000020       d   o   c   k   e   r   -   c   o   m   p   o   s   e    
0000040   e   x   e   c       p   h   p       b   i   n   /   c   o   n
0000060   s   o   l   e       a   p   p   :   s   e   n   d   -   s   m
0000100   s  \n   `   `   `
0000105
```

#### UPDATE

The issue came from those char: ```

that were present in my `cron file` before and after my command

Comment: Maybe you have misunderstood CRON. You install a job ONCE that will be run by CRON every 15 minutes. It seems you are trying to install a cron job every 15 minutes? Or maybe I have the wrong end of the CronJob :)

Comment: Yeah the cron will be used to do that eventually, in the meantime though I need to run it manually to see if it acts properly, and the error syntax prevent me for doing that

Comment: can you run `docker-compose exec php bin/console app:send-sms` without error?

Comment: Yes this command work fine and has several tests

Comment: you run `docker-compose` i think first you need to go to the directory that you have your docker-compose.yml file and then run it

Comment: Check if there are any invisible characters in the file. Show in your question the output of `od -c sms.cron`. What editor did you use to create the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file `sms.cron` seems to contain lines with 3 backticks

````
```
````

before and after the line shown in the question.
Remove these additional lines.

Comment: That was it ! Thanks !

Comment: I had the schedule in `"` quotes, after removing it, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a file I ported from windows. Did not work until I changed `\r\n` into `\n`.
Found it only because of this error message here. Thanks to all!